# Find and replace with wildcards in R

Tags: r, replace, find, wildcard, str-replace

I need to find any occurrences of when a value in a dataset has 3 `.x`'s (e.g. `A1.1.1.1`) and replace it with another name (E.g. B1). I currently have this, which works for `A1.1.1.1` but I need it to be able to work for `A1.x.x.x` where x is any number (less than 10). Is there a way to adapt this so it works?

`node_data$test<-str_replace(node_data$test, "A1.1.1.1", "B1")`

Comment: Perhaps mention the output that you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
ex_str <- c("A1.1.1.1", "D.1.1", "C.1.1.1", "J.2.1.3", "J.2.33.3")

str_replace(ex_str, "\\..\\..\\..", "B1")

[1] "A1B1"     "D.1.1"    "CB1"      "JB1"      "J.2.33.3"
```

Note that in this example the character after each dot does not have to be the same, so the fourth entry of the example vector is replaced. However, the '.x.x.x' being matched can only have one character after each '.' so the fifth entry is not replaced.

Alternatively, the following regex will replace the matched segment of each string with `.B1.B1.B1`

```
str_replace(ex_str, "\\..\\..\\..", ".B1.B1.B1")

[1] "A1.B1.B1.B1" "D.1.1"       "C.B1.B1.B1"  "J.B1.B1.B1"  "J.2.33.3"
```

Comment: Glad to help, Kathryn! Be sure to mark my response as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
gsub('A', 'B', gsub('(\\.\\d){3}' ,'', 'A1.1.2.3'))
# [1] "B1"
```

or this:

```
gsub('(A)(\\d)(\\.\\d){3}' ,'B\\2', 'A1.5.6.7')
# [1] "B1"
```

or this:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace('A1.1.2.3', '(A)(\\d)(\\.\\d){3}' ,'B\\2')
# [1] "B1"
```